# Windows Phone 8.1 - Programmatically scrolling in GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, scroll, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make programmatically scrolling in GridView and prevent user from doing it by himself. I tried to do something like in code below:

```
GridView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
GridView.ScrollIntoView(GridView.Items[10]);
GridView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

Unfortunately after disabling vertical scroll bar display of GridView back to first row.

**EDIT:** After all there was really simple solution. Instead of changing values of `VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty` I disabled `VerticalScrollModeProperty`.

Comment: Thing is that GridView's content must be clickable. The GridView's dimension is (7 columns) x (6 rows). User with gesture can shrink GridView to single row and here I need scrolling to row of selected before item.

Comment: This only solve problem with part where GridView is scrolling but the main problem is what to do after scrolling. I need to disable scrolling so user don't use it (content must be clickable), but display go back to first row.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not getting your requirement clearly but it'd be better to use ScrollViewer on top of your gridview and scroll it programmatically using:

```
ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(Offset Value);
```

Or using PropertyMetaData. You can also enable/disable the scrollviewer based on your requirements.